# Why has the behaviour of Lazy.CreateFromValue changed in F# between .NET framework versions?

Tags: .net, f#, lazy-evaluation, .net-framework-version

I just encountered a change in behaviour between framework versions when compiling this piece of code in F#:

```
let test = Lazy.CreateFromValue 1
```

Compiled against .NET framework 2.0, the expression results in an "already created" Lazy object, that is:

```
test.IsValueCreated = true
```

When compiled against .NET framework 4.0, the expression results in an "unevaluated" lazy object, that is:

```
 test.IsValueCreated = false
```

Only after accessing **test.Value** in the latter case the two are equivalent.

I couldn't find any reference to this change anywhere, hence my question is why does this behave differently and what was the reasoning behind the change (it's breaking). In my opinion, the behaviour in .NET 2.0 makes more sense - creating a Lazy object from a concrete value should result in an "already evaluated" lazy object.

Comment: If it's already evaluated, it can hardly be said to be lazily evaluated...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes, but in .NET 2, it's _not lazily evaluated_, so I do see why there's some confusion.  It's more that fsharp.core does weird stuff in .NET 2 to make it look like lazy exists, but it's never lazy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before .NET 4.0, the framework didn't ship with `Lazy<'T>`.

That's ancient history, but F# originally had its own implementation of `Lazy`, distinct from what we have today - you can catch a glimpse of it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jomo_fisher/2007/09/27/adventures-in-f-lazy-like-a-fox/).

That implementation was abandoned when it became clear that `Lazy` is coming to the framework proper. Instead, F# 2.0 shipped with its own implementation of `System.Lazy<'T>` (note the namespace) in `FSharp.Core` assembly. That's the implementation you can still see [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/84b6da1bfcdc748ba1a79444f70e04708c6d3324/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L6296). The idea was that once .NET 4.0 is available, F# will seamlessly pick up `System.Lazy<'T>` from there instead, without breaking the users. Which worked for the most part, but it wasn't entirely without problems.

You'll note that F# implementation has a `CreateFromValue` member that yields a value of type `Lazy<'T>` already marked as evaluated. Which makes perfect sense semantically, since you're obviously giving it an evaluated value in the first place.

Why is it then that .NET 4.0 implementation doesn't do the same?

If you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Lazy<'T>`, you'll find that there's no way of creating it in an evaluated state. There's no `CreateFromValue` member on it, and no constructor takes a value of `'T`, only a `Func<'T>`. `CreateFromValue` is actually provided as an [extension method](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/84b6da1bfcdc748ba1a79444f70e04708c6d3324/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L6379) by F#.

It would be quite easy to provide this method in a non-breaking way:

```
static member CreateFromValue(value : 'T) : System.Lazy<'T> =
    let x = System.Lazy<'T>.Create(fun () -> value)
    x.Value |> ignore
    x
```

but that didn't happen for some reason. Perhaps it was a deliberate choice - I suppose you could argue both for and against such change - but perhaps it was an oversight. If you look at the convoluted history of this type, I think you'll agree that it could have been worse.

Answer (score 4):

The [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class was added to the framework in .NET 4.  The F# support for lazy is more of a stub to allow the API to work on .NET 2, but doesn't provide a truly lazy implementation when using this API.

The F# compiler created it's [own lazy type](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/84b6da1bfcdc748ba1a79444f70e04708c6d3324/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L3313-L3328) for .NET 2, as it predated the .NET 4 version.  In .NET 2, the lazy type just sets the value explicitly, and isn't truly lazy (see the [source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/84b6da1bfcdc748ba1a79444f70e04708c6d3324/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L3313-L3328)) when using `CreateFromValue`.

Because of this, the `CreateFromValue` [extension on .NET 4](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/84b6da1bfcdc748ba1a79444f70e04708c6d3324/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L6380) is truly lazy - it instantiates the lazy type with a function that returns the value.  On .NET 2, the [internal type is used instead](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/84b6da1bfcdc748ba1a79444f70e04708c6d3324/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L6371), which fulfills the API of `Lazy<'T>.CreateFromValue`, but isn't truly lazy.

Comment: That's simply not true. F# had a "fully-functional" `Lazy` in .NET 2, but since there was no `Lazy` in the framework at that time, [it had its own implementation](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/84b6da1bfcdc748ba1a79444f70e04708c6d3324/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L6296).

Comment: `CreateFromValue` is implemented differently, but as @MarkSeemann noted, it can hardly be said to be lazily evaluated if it's already evaluated. If anything, F# version actually makes more sense.

Comment: @scrwtp It wasn't lazy if you use createfromvalue in .NET 2 - I'll reword, because I wrote it poorly.